# Existe alguma nomenclatura para variáveis definidas por underline/underscore?

Tags: terminologia, convenções-de-nome

Sei que existem algumas regras e convenções para a nomenclatura de variáveis na programação, como *CamelCase*, *PascalCase*, etc...

**Qual é o termo utilizado** para uma variável de nome composta (palavras separadas por "_")?

**Exemplo:** `nome_da_variavel`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conheço essa separação por underline pelo nome de *Snake Case*.

De acordo com a referência da Wikipédia, o nome snake case foi criado pela comunidade Ruby.

## Exemplos

Em algumas linguagens, é comum ver a utilização do snake_case para nomeclatures de algumas funções ou variáveis, como é o caso da linguagem Python. Parece que a galera que desenvolve nessa linguagem tem preferência por definir funções ou variáveis com esse padrão.

Exemplo:

```
 def minha_funcao(**args):
     pass

 resultado = minha_funcao(1)
```

Comumente, em Python, vemos o uso do snake case combinado com o lowercase.
Talvez seja por isso que  de acordo com a Wikipédia, o nome utilizado pelo Guia de Estilo do Python era *lower_case_with_underscores*.

No PHP também vemos esse padrão sendo aplicado às funções e variáveis, sendo que a pequena diferença é que, em casos de variáveis consideradas *Super Globais* linguagem, é escrito em uppercase.

Veja:

```
 $usuario_id = obter_id_usuario($_GET)
```

Referências:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case

Answer (score 6):

Sim, este padrão é comumente chamado de *snake case* (*snake_case*, neste caso :p).

Não existe um nome oficial para este padrão, *snake case* foi o nome que a comunidade do Ruby deu a ele (isso mesmo, não foi o pessoal do Python).

O [guia de estilos do Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) chama este padrão de *`lower_case_with_underscores`*.

Comment: Poxa, fiquei triste em saber que a galera do Python não aderiu a possíveis  trocadilhos de "snake" com "python". Pelo visto, eles devem ser bem sérios kkkkkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters `import antigravity`

Answer (score 6):

Snakecase ou Underscorecase são os termos utilizados para o case que usa "_".

Snake case é bem antigo e vem do início do C, porém recebeu esse nome recentemente.

[Aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) tem uma boa noção sobre todas as convenções que eu creio que sejam uteis no seu estudo.

[Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)

Comment: Gostei da lista de convenções! +1 ;)