# Como escolher uma convenção para nome de variáveis e funções?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, estilo-de-codificação, convenções

Estou passando pela segunda empresa de desenvolvimento e em ambas não tem uma convenção própria para usar nas declarações, nos códigos pego funções declaradas da seguinte forma:

> 1. PHP e jQuery

```
function nome_pessoa();
function nomePessoa();
function nomepessoa();
function Nome_pessoa();
```

Eu sei que ambas as escolhas funcionam mas fica muito "feio" pois tem momentos que no mesmo arquivo tem uma função sendo chamada assim `function nome_aluno()` e depois em outro local no mesmo arquivo `nomeResponsavel()` vamos dizer assim, e encontro também funções declaras com 3 ou 4 _ (underline) `function nome_dos_responsáveis()`, inclusive não sei se isto pode causar lentidão no sistema, não quero criar uma discussão e sim saber qual a forma mais utilizada por vocês, sei que também pode ser um assunto muito pessoal como escolha de IDEs para desenvolvimento, mas quero me habituar a algo que seja mais claro.

Comment: Podem explicar os `-1`? acho esta questão bem importante e gostava de saber porque outros não acham.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Até que ponto devo seguir as convenções, onde posso aplicar específicos padrões de estilo próprio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/91) e [Existe alguma nomenclatura para variáveis definidas por underline/underscore?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215738/91)

Comment: Já fizeram uma pergunta semelhante para o Java (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/132 - Certamente, parte do que há por lá (mas não tudo) se aplica aqui.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De fato, precisa seguir uma convenção, isso é ponto que já sabe. A convenção pode mudar de acordo com a tecnologia, então se está programando em PHP pode ser uma, e em JavaScript pode ser outra, isto é normal porque a cada linguagem tem suas peculiaridades.

Alguém pode brincar que em PHP a convenção é não seguir convenção, afinal muita coisa na própria biblioteca e linguagem não seguem. Claro que isso é ruim, só porque a linguagem é ruim não quer dizer que deva seguir isso.

Há até programadores que criam funções auxiliares com a convenção "certa" para usar no lugar da função do PHP que não segue a convenção. Poucos fazem, a maioria porque não pensam nisso, não sabem como fazer ou alguns que acham que não vale o esforço para fazer e manter a performance que dá um pouco mais de trabalho e exige conhecimento além do PHP.

Fica pior entre os diversos *frameworks* disponíveis:

| PHPProject | Classes | Methods | Properties | Functions | Variables |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AkelosFramework | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | lower_case | lower_case |
| CakePHPFramework | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase |
| CodeIgniterFramework | Proper_Case | lower_case | lower_case | lower_case | lower_case |
| Concrete5CMS | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | lower_case | lower_case |
| DoctrineORM | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase |
| DrupalCMS | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | lower_case | lower_case |
| JoomlaCMS | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase |
| modxCMS | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase | lower_case |
| PearFramework | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase |  |  |
| PradoFramework | PascalCase | camelCase | Pascal/camel |  | lower_case |
| SimplePieRSS | PascalCase | lower_case | lower_case | lower_case | lower_case |
| SymfonyFramework | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase |
| WordPressCMS |  |  |  | lower_case | lower_case |
| ZendFramework | PascalCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase | camelCase |

[Fonte](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149321/389).

[Algo oficial](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

O importante é escolher uma e seguir. Ninguém pode dizer qual é a melhor para você.

Eu gosto de `NomePessoa()`. Em PHP nem tanto. O que vejo mais é o uso de `nome_pessoa()`. Mas se for método, aí muda para `nomePessoa()`.

Em JS é mais comum `nomePessoa()`.

[Convenção para JS de, talvez, o maior guru da linguagem](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html). E a [convenção da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style). E ainda a [convenção da Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html).

Só note que [jQuery não é uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101) então não tem que ter convenção para ele e sim para ao JS.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Ainda que seja muito importante ter um estilo definido quando trabalhamos em equipa isso é difícil de implementar em código antigo, e tem uma componente muito grande de gosto pessoal. Ou seja, têm (e devem!) sentar-se a discutir, decidir e implementar.

Como disse há uma componente grande de "gosto pessoal" por isso o mais importante é mesmo tomar uma decisão. Contudo, uma regra instituída pela comunidade JavaScript é que função só têm letra grande quando forem construtores de classes, e variáveis só têm letra grande quando forem constantes.

De resto sugiro dar uma olhada à declaração de estilo do Vue.js que está agora a ser discutido pela comunidade (em fase Beta): https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/ como ponto de partida.

A minha experiência em JavaScript diz-me que a maneira correta dos exemplos que deste é

> camelCase - `function nomePessoa();` - ✓

De resto a wikipedia tem uma lista extensa de guias de estilo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions#Coding_conventions_for_languages

Mas novamente, é importante decidirem juntos e aplicar, mesmo em código antigo.

Answer (score 2):

Existem diversas convenções que você poderia adotar. A mais utilizada em geral, e que cabe perfeitamente tanto no **PHP** quanto no **jQuery** é a chamada **CamelCase**.

---

#### Definição:

> **CamelCase** é a denominação em inglês para a prática de escrever palavras compostas ou frases, onde cada palavra é iniciada com maiúsculas e unidas sem espaços. É um padrão largamente utilizado em diversas linguagens de programação, como `Java`, `C#`, `Ruby`, `PHP` e `Python`, principalmente nas definições de `classes` e `objetos`.

---

#### Normas do CamelCase:

A primeira letra de uma palavra composta por CamelCase pode ou não ser capitalizada, não há consenso sobre a maneira certa de sua utilização. Existem duas formas de classificá-la: a primeira é conhecida como **UpperCamelCase** (de letra inicial maiúscula, também conhecida como PascalCase) e a segunda **lowerCamelCase** (de letra inicial minúscula).

Existem algumas normas a serem seguidas nessa convenção. A norma **lowerCamelCase** implica que palavras compostas devem ser iniciadas por letras minúsculas. Usa-se essa norma para definir `variáveis` e `métodos`.

Exemplos:

- `$nomeCompleto;`
- `$valorDesconto;`
- `$tipoCliente;`

A norma **UpperCamelCase** (que também pode ser chamada de `PascalCase`) implica que palavras devem ser iniciadas por letras maiúsculas. Usa-se essa norma na definição de `classes` em `orientação a objetos`.

Exemplos:

```
class ClienteChave { 

}

class ProdutoPrincipal {

}

class LojaMatriz {

}
```

---

#### Conclusão

O mais importante é seguir um padrão, uma norma ou convenção. A melhor escolha depende de você, ou ainda em certos casos pode ser a partir de uma determinação da sua empresa, uma convenção da própria linguagem em que está desenvolvendo.

Answer (score 1):

O convenção seguida pelos programadores profissionais na linguagem PHP é a seguinte:

```
<?php

// Para classes e métodos a convenção é a seguinte:

class CadastroCliente
{
    function nomePessoa($nome, $sobrenome)
    {

    }

    function CPF($numero)
    {

    }
}

// Para funções a convenção é a seguinte:

function nome_pessoa($nome, $sobrenome) {

}

?>
```

Lembrando que nunca defina nomes de classes, métodos ou funções em português. Use nomes e comentários em inglês, mesmo sendo uma classe ou uma função que só vai ter utilidade no Brasil. Exemplo: Classe ou função que valida CNPJ ou CPF.
Veja como fica mais padronizado as declarações em inglês.

```
<?php

// For classes and methods the convention is as follows:

class ValidateDocument
{
    function CNPJ($number)
    {

    }

    function CPF($number)
    {

    }
}

// For functions the convention is as follows:

function persons_name($first_name, $last_name) {

}

?>

<?php

// O nome da variável que vai receber a instância deve ter o mesmo nome da classe:
$ValidateDocument = new ValidateDocument();
$ValidateDocument->CPF(012.345.678-9);

// Constantes devem ser declaradas com todas as letras maiúsculas, separadas por underscore:
define(SOU_UMA_CONSTANTE, true);

// Variáveis de uso geral devem ser declaradas com todas a letras minúsculas, separadas por underscore:
$first_name = 'Leandro';
$last_name  = 'Sciola';

// Alinhe as variáveis pelo sinal de atribuição:
$nome   = '';
$genero = '';
$idade  = 0;
$cpf    = 0;

?>
```