# Como resolver o problema de duplicação de código?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, herança

No Wordpress estou a criar um ecrã customizado na área de administração.

Para isso estou a estender a minha classe `customProductsListTable` a classe `WP_List_Table`:

```
class customProductsListTable extends WP_List_Table
```

Eu tenho outra classe para outro ecrã customizado que extende a mesma classe `WP_List_Table`:

```
class customReviewsListTable extends WP_List_Table
```

O problema é que nas classes `customProductsListTable` e `customReviewsListTable` criei alguns métodos que são comuns e que não existem na classe `WP_List_Table`.

Então temos o seguinte cenário:

- As classes `customReviewsListTable` e `customProductsListTable` fazem overwrite de alguns métodos da classe `WP_List_Table`, mas o código se comporta de maneira diferente em cada classe.
- As classes `customReviewsListTable` e `customProductsListTable` possuem métodos novos mas com o mesmo comportamento.

Claramente estou a duplicar código nas 2 classes, porém não podemos em PHP herdar mais de uma classe.

Como resolver o problema de duplicação de código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie uma classe intermediária, algo assim:

```
class CustomListTable extends WP_List_Table
```

Nela sobrescreva os métodos que deseja e crie os novos que serão comuns. Então herde assim:

```
class CustomProductsListTable extends CustomListTable

class CustomReviewsListTable extends CustomListTable
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Extends.php).

Nestas classes poderá sobrescrever e criar métodos novos que sejam específicos para elas.

Mantive sua nomenclatura, mas note que ela diverge da usada no WordPress. Isto é confuso. Se bem que é confuso para [todo o PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243958/101).

Tenho a impressão que esta classe intermediária pode ser até abstrata, mas sem ver todo o contexto não posso afirmar.

Comment: Obrigado. Sim, a classe intermédia poderá ser abstrata com os métodos abstratos nos casos que possuem comportamento diferente e os restantes que possuem comportamento igual, não serão assinados como `abstract`. Também não quero que a classe intermédia seja instanciada.

Comment: outra forma de resolver seria criando uma ou mais interfaces para esses metodos.