# Usar underline em C# seria uma boa prática?

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome

A pergunta é referente a padrão de desenvolvimento e boas práticas.

Eu venho de um mundo JavaScript e PHP, trabalho há 12 anos com desenvolvimento, e estou muito acostumado a usar underlines `_` nas variáveis, como por exemplo `nome_completo`.

Porém estou iniciando a desenvolver em C# e não é costume fazer isso em linguagens de alto nível, na faculdade quando eu vi Java já percebia isso, é costume se escrever `nomeCompleto`.

Se eu continuar a utilizar *underlines* no desenvolvimento em C#, seria uma boa prática? Alguém utiliza este padrão também? Ou eu vou ter que ceder e mudar este comportamento?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nem é boa e nem é má prática, é estilo.

Sem falar que boa prática costuma ser uma regra sem explicação, então a pessoa toma como algo bom sem nem saber porque e acaba virando má prática porque ela usa algo que potencialmente bom do jeito errado e se torna ruim. Se as pessoas desapegassem dessa ideia de boa prática programariam melhor.

Pode ser usado normalmente, a linguagem aceita, então não é ruim, se fosse, ela proibiria.

[O padrão que se convencionou adotar em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101) é não usar `_` nem no início, nem no meio dos identificadores de todo tipo. Algumas pessoas violam isso, mas fica estranho para quem está acostumado com códigos nessa linguagem.

Hoje o *underline* tem semântica específica na linguagem (descarte de valor) usando sozinho (sem outros caracteres), então pode dificultar um pouco a leitura de alguns códigos, nada grave, mas cria alguma confusão visual.

Isso nada tem a ver com a linguagem ser de alto nível, depende de cultura criada, só isso.

Só lembrando que JS não adota esse estilo também ([Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html), [Douglas Crockford](https://www.crockford.com/code.html)), algumas pessoas adotam. [Em PHP é inconsistente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243958/101). Então provavelmente não seguia a tal da "boa prática".

Se fizer assim em C# seu código parecerá alienígena para outras pessoas, prefira o *pascalCase* ou *CamelCase*, dependendo do cenário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela opinião, realmente pareceria alienígina, concordo contigo. Em todas as empresas que eu trabalhei existe a briga "se usa ou não usa underline", é semelhante à briga "chave na mesma linha ou chave embaixo" (sou do time chave embaixo hehehe)

Comment: Não é uma opinião, é um fato, não damos opiniões aqui.

Comment: ok, obrigado pelo fato

Comment: @Maniero, mas o JS usa underline sim.

Comment: @Miriancherbo eu citei duas referências você pode citar as suas.

Comment: @Maniero, citou sim, mas não são links oficiais da linguagem ou do criadouro dela. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Vari%C3%A1veis

Comment: @Miriancherbo Mas são guias os que as pessoas seguem. O que você citou não é um guia, e mesmo que fosse não seria oficial porque não existe um oficial. Poder usar não quer dizer que deve usar.

Answer (score 2):

O que eu lhe recomendo é usar a convenção de nomes da equipa ou projeto em que você está inserido. Isso é mais importante do que "debater qual convenção de nomes é melhor usar".

Fazendo isso você garante que todos os programadores usam a mesma nomenclatura e se entendem. No final o projeto no mínimo será consistente a nível de nomes, o que acaba valendo bem mais do que parece. E também limita a margem para brigas uma vez que todos usam a mesma convenção de nomes.

Agora se você vai começar um projeto novo, sendo sozinho ou com uma equipa em que você decide a nomenclatura, pode optar por qualquer uma. Até pode ser que todos os programadores estejam mais habituados a snake case (os underscores) e que sejam mais produtivos dessa forma.

Vale salientar que a Microsoft definiu os [padrões de nomenclatura que eles recomendam](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), como o @Maniero já mencionou, e são os que deve seguir caso não tenha uma opinião forte para optar por um deles.

Se seguir os padrões de nomenclatura definidos pela Microsoft, o seu código sai com a nomenclatura mais utilizada no mundo C# e por isso o seu código será mais natural a outros programadores C# e vice versa.