# Como posso melhorar esse código?

Tags: java, revisão-de-código

Estou apredendo java e encontrei esse desafio porem ao terminar achei que o código ficou muito poluido porem não consigo pensar no modo de melhorar, acredito que usando POO seria bem mais fácil porem não posso usar. Como posso deixar esse código mais "limpo"?

```
/*Uma academia deseja fazer um senso entre seus clientes para descobrir o mais alto, o mais baixo, a mais gordo e o mais magro, para isto você deve fazer um programa quepergunte
a cada um dos clientes da academia seu código, sua altura e seu peso. O final da digitação de dados deve ser dada quando o usuário digitar 0 (zero) no campo código. Ao encerrar
o programa também deve ser informados os códigos e valores do clente mais alto, do mais baixo, do mais gordo e do mais magro, além da média das alturas e dos pesos dos clientes*/

package Exercício062;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Varaáveis
        int id = 0;
        double altura = 0;
        double peso = 0;

        //Primeiros valores
        //ID
        System.out.printf("ID: ");
        id = read.nextInt();
        //Altura
        System.out.printf("Altura: ");
        altura = read.nextDouble();
        //Peso
        System.out.printf("Peso: ");
        peso = read.nextDouble();

        //Colocações
        int id_gordo, id_magro, id_alto, id_baixo;
        id_gordo = id_magro = id_alto = id_baixo = id;
        double peso_gordo = peso;
        double peso_magro = peso;
        double alt_alto = altura;
        double alt_baixo = altura;

        while(id != 0){
            System.out.printf("ID: ");
            id = read.nextInt();
            if(id == 0){
                break;
            }
            System.out.printf("Altura: ");
            altura = read.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Peso: ");
            peso = read.nextDouble();

            if(peso > peso_gordo){
                id_gordo = id;
                peso_gordo = peso;
            }
            if(peso < peso_magro){
                id_magro = id;
                peso_magro = peso;
            }
            if(altura > alt_alto){
                id_alto = id;
                alt_alto = altura;
            }
            if(altura < alt_baixo){
                id_baixo = id;
                alt_baixo = altura;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("O mais gordo é o: " + id_gordo + "\nO mais leve é o: " + id_magro + "\nO mais alto é o: " + id_alto + "\nO mais baixo é o: " + id_baixo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Para um exercício está bom, para um caso real precisaria de muito mais informação para dizer o que pode ser melhor. O resto é praticamente questão de estilo e detalhes pouco importantes para o estágio atual de aprendizado.

Comment: @hkotsubo desculpe, estou conhecendo o stack agora, marquei como correta novamente, extremamente interessante essa função MAX e MIN_VALUE, sua resposta me ajudou muito e entendi muito bem a logica do código e as dicas, obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Sem saber os requisitos é difícil afirmar o que seria o "certo" ou mais adequado, mas em linhas gerais, dá para sugerir algumas coisas.*</sup>

---

Se vc faz o `break` quando o `id` for zero, não precisa testar essa condição novamente no `while` (pois `break` interrompe o *loop* imediatamente), então poderia fazer `while (true)`.

Além disso, não precisa repetir a leitura dos dados antes do *loop* e dentro dele. Talvez você tenha feito isso para iniciar o *loop* com as variáveis que guardam os valores mínimos e máximos, mas não precisa disso. Uma opção é inicializar o valor mínimo com o maior valor possível (pois assim qualquer coisa que for digitada será menor que ele), e o máximo com o menor valor possível.

E se está usando [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), aproveite as [opções de formatação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) que este método disponibiliza, em vez de concatenar strings. E onde não precisa imprimir variáveis, pode usar simplesmente [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-), que não pula a linha ao final.

Por fim, a [convenção de nomenclatura em Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) não recomenda o [*snake_case*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215738/112052) para nomes de variáveis, e sim o [*camelCase*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160947/112052):

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

int idGordo, idMagro, idAlto, idBaixo;
idGordo = idMagro = idAlto = idBaixo = 0;
double pesoGordo = Double.MIN_VALUE;
double pesoMagro = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double altAlto = Double.MIN_VALUE;
double altBaixo = Double.MAX_VALUE;

while (true) {
    System.out.print("ID: ");
    int id = read.nextInt();
    if (id == 0) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.print("Altura: ");
    double altura = read.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Peso: ");
    double peso = read.nextDouble();

    if (peso > pesoGordo) {
        idGordo = id;
        pesoGordo = peso;
    }
    if (peso < pesoMagro) {
        idMagro = id;
        pesoMagro = peso;
    }
    if (altura > altAlto) {
        idAlto = id;
        altAlto = altura;
    }
    if (altura < altBaixo) {
        idBaixo = id;
        altBaixo = altura;
    }
}
System.out.printf("O mais gordo é o: %d\nO mais leve é o : %d \nO mais alto é o: %d\nO mais baixo é o: %d\n", idGordo, idMagro, idAlto, idBaixo);
```

Claro que sempre dá para melhorar mais, como por exemplo verificar se o `id` se repete (pode? não pode?), se os valores digitados são números válidos (se não digitar um número, dará erro, e [`Scanner` tem algumas pegadinhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/112052) que podem acontecer), verificar faixas de valores (entendo que peso e altura não podem ser negativos, por exemplo), e por aí vai. Se os valores serão usados posteriormente, poderia usar uma estrutura (array ou [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), por exemplo), etc.

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/463726/112052) (que foi apagada) chegou a sugerir recursão, mas sinceramente, não faz o menor sentido para esse caso. Se quiser entender melhor, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438762/112052).